# R Hist Function with Lattice Package

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

I am learning R.  I am reading a book that has the below hist function which is basically removing 0 values and values >=1000 from the histogram.

Problem is I don't understand what the code is saying and the book does not explain it.

What are the conditions inside the () and why is !0 specified twice?  Is there another way to write this code that is a little more intuitive?  I am using the lattice package.

Your help is much appreciate!

```
hist(don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0][don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0]<=10000])
```

Comment: This `hist()` function has nothing to do with Lattice. And that command is odd, it's probable better to do `hist(don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0 & don$TGiving<=10000])`. What book is this?!?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification on lattice.  DATA MINING AND BUSINESS ANALYTICS WITH R is the book.  Your code is much more intuitive and easy to read.  Works exactly the same.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This a pretty cluncky way of doing it. Perhaps it would be easier to see what was happening if you created a temporary variable with the first part of that expression which removes the values below 0 and then worked with it.

```
 temp <- don$TGiving[don$TGiving!=0]  # remove items below 0
 hist( temp[ temp  < 1000 ] )         # remove items above 1000  and then plot
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use `lattice`, you should use `histogram()` instead of `hist()`.  `subset()` is useful too.

```
 set.seed(101)
 don <- data.frame(TGiving=round(rgamma(1000,shape=5,scale=100)))
 library(lattice)
 histogram(~TGiving,data=subset(don,TGiving!=0 & TGiving<1000))
```